# Starting a pokemon-like game project in C#

Tags: c#, class, items

I'm a beginner in C# and I want to start a little project similar to Pokemon in C#. While creating my classes, I am having some problems with the Attacks since not all Pokemon moves do damage. My class was looking like this for now:

```
private string Name
private int Power
private int Accuracy
private TypePokemon Type //like water,fire,grass,etc
private int PP
```

what would I need to change since some attacks will not be dealing damage but healing, giving more Attack, etc? Same things with the Items, some will give HP, some will give buffs to the Pokemon, some gives PPs to moves, etc...

Some terms for non-Pokemon players...

- HP- Hit points of the Pokemon, basically how much life it has.
- "Giving more attack" - increasing the amount of HP damage done by future attacks
- "give buffs" - Improving various stats, such as Attack, Speed, HP, etc

Comment: I would like to suggest the close voters hold off on this one as the OP has clearly put in effort and can identify the problem if not the solution - the question is a little broad but I'm sure it can be scoped with a little help!

Comment: I'm not familiar with pokemon games. Can you describe in a little more detail what the difference is between an action and an attack? The obvious for me is to either create different Attack() or Action() methods or to have an Attack() with a "damage" of zero... but it's very hard to know without knowing how the game rules work

Comment: @Liath, your attitude is commendable, but you probably should edit the question into shape instead of asking people not to close it (since you agree it's too broad).

Comment: Minor stylistic points private variables should be written either _name or name, public properties and methods use capitals

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I've tried to add some comments for the OP to help them - I don't know the game well enough :-(

Comment: When i made a game like this i made power a negative number and then set a bool for aggreessive and if aggressie== true then can hit enemy if aggressive == false then hit my ally/self then on readup if power <=0 then display "--"

Comment: Is the answer simply that that Power/Damage should be a property of the attack/action rather than the creature?

Comment: agree with Liath, please explain the (relevant) rules of Pokemon to those of us who don't know.  Explaining the rules might help you think about how to structure your code too.

Answer (score 2):

One of these options may work for you, but I suggest diving deeply into the paradigms of each. Links for keywords incoming.

- If a move doesn't deal damage, leave it with a `Power` of 0 - since some damaging moves also inflict states or effect other results, that framework will have to exist anyway for all moves. As suggested by BradleyDotNET, this could be done by an [`Action`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.action%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate invoked every time the attack is used.
- Since the `int` is optional, consider making it an [`int?`/`Nullable<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) (which allows it to be `null`).
- Since not every move has `Damage` don't include it in your base class - instead make an [`abstract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx) class, and `DamageMove` inherits from `Move` and adds a `Damage` property.

Comment: One other suggestion, provide a "Special Action" `Action` delegate that can be invoked to cause the side-effect to occur.

Comment: Basically what I meant by the first suggestion, but I'll incorporate that